# Naming binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Given a string of 1's and 0's, containing the same number of 1's as 0's, is there a way to uniquely "name" each string with a number such that it is computationally easy to go between this "name" and this string.

Here is an example of what would be a bad solution:
ordering the strings from smallest to largest and naming each based on its position in this list.
This solution is poor because converting between the name and string requires a lot of computation.

I would also like the size of these names to be minimized. 
Another poor solution would be to have the name be the first n-1 digits of a string of length n. Example: string = 1011010001, name = 101101000. Although converting between string and name is easy, the size of the name isn't really all that much smaller.

Consider the case where the string has a length of 10. It is easy to see that there are 252 possible strings. Therefor an optimal solution would have the names of the string consist of a list of 8 1's and 0's.

I would like a solution that can be generalized to a string of any even length. Also, I'm not necessarily looking for the perfect solution, just one that works.

Thanks

Comment: The name of $1011010001$ could be $02359$ . This string represents the positions of the $1´s$. $0$ is the first postition, $2$ the third position and so on. The remaining positions are filled with $0´s$

Comment: If $s$ is your string, is it too much computation to name it with the integer whose binary representation is the string $1s$? I.e., the name of $1011010001$ would be $(11011010001)_2=1745$ in base-ten.

Comment: naming a string using the positions of the 1's makes a name that is larger than the original string when written in binary (if you converted 02359 to binary it would be long) the goal is to make the name shorter than the string

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let the name be the integer that the string denotes as a binary numeral:
$$
name\colon b_{n-1} \dotsc b_0 \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n b_k 2^k\quad\text{($n\ge 0$)}.
$$
This is unambiguous on the language $L = \{s\in \{0,1\}^*\mid \text{# of $0$s in $s = $ of $1$s in $s$}\}$: Only the empty string is mapped to $0$. If $name(s) = name(t)$ with $s = b_n \dotsc b_0, t = b_m \dotsc b_0 \in L$, then clearly $s$ and $t$ can only differ by having different numbers of $0$s in their leftmost positions. But then their number of initial $0$s must be equal, as the two strings have the same number of zeros and have to agree from the first $1$ to their ends.

Comment: The goal in mind is to minimize the length of this name so using the string itself as a name would not be ideal. I mentioned this in the question as an example

Comment: An integer is not a string. The $name$ function displayed has integer values.

Comment: What I am trying to do is compress a string of ones and zeros into a shorter name which is easily converted back into the string. both the name and string should consist only of ones and zeros. The essence of the problem is data compressions. I have a string of ones and zeros which is taking up n bits of data (n being the length of the string). I would like to make a name that uses less data (writing this name in 1's and 0's allows comparing the two to be quite easy).

Comment: How much more compression do you expect to get, though? I don't believe you can get more than a constant factor better.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your comment that your question is a compression problem. However, the number of strings containing $n$ $0$'s and $n$ $1$'s is equal to the
[central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{2n}{n}$. By Stirling formula, $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}({n \over e})^n$ and it follows that $\binom{2n}{n} \sim {4^n \over \sqrt{\pi n}}$. Now, the number of strings of length $2n$ is $4^n$. This means that you can only hope to save $\log_2(\sqrt{\pi n}) \approx 0.825 + \log_2 n$ bits, a very small number compared to $n$. For instance, if $n = 2^{270}$, a rough estimate of the number of atoms in the universe, you would only save $270$ bits. Is it really worth trying, knowing that you would also have to store the compression algorithm?

Comment: I also realize that the compression would be minimal. This was just a specific case of a more general problem I was looking at where you have a particular ratio of 1's to 0's. for example maybe the ratio of 1's to 0's is 1 to 3.

Comment: Also, I did some calculations regarding the ideal amount of compression possible in this particular case (that being 1 to 1 for the ratio of 0's to 1's) and found that the amount of bits saved increases by about 2 every time you increase the string length by a factor of 10. eg. 10 bit string = 2 bits can be saved 1000 bit string = 6 bits can be saved ect.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding, say, from the beginning of the string, write each letter as itself if it's preceded by equal numbers of zeros and ones, and else write it as a one if it's in the minority in the preceding values and as a zero otherwise. This slightly raises the number of ones in the string, and you can try to compress the resulting string by making use of that, e.g. with a prefix code that has shorter codes for sequences with more ones. As J.-E. Pin has pointed out, the potential for compression is very limited, and this will certainly not exhaust even that small potential, but it might be worth a try.